# Sqoop not able to transform mysql timestamp to hive bigint

Tags: mysql, hadoop, timestamp, hive, sqoop

I have a timestamp column on mysql, and adding --map-column-hive option to sqoop is not working, I just get a NULL value in this field.

```
--map-column-hive creation_time=bigint,last_update=bigint
```

Using a query with this "unix_timestamp(creation_time) creation_time" works well though, but it requires to list all the fields.

Any advice?

Thx!

Comment: Gotta ask, why not use the Hive timestamp type?

Comment: the timestamp hive type appears to not hold the real timestamp value (seconds since 1970-1-1, UTC), but a sort of string with the date on the server timezone. If I would use several servers in different timezones the same data would have two different values.